# Вывести строки если пусто - все, если не пусто - по условию

Tags: sql, база-данных, case

Дано: таблица orders, в которой есть customer, переменная @cust

Нужно: 
ВЫБРАТЬ всё

ИЗ orders

ГДЕ (

ЕСЛИ @cust пустая - вывести все строки;
ЕСЛИ @cust не пустая - вывести строки, где customer=@cust)

Т.е. если переменная пустая - вывести все строки, а если нет, то только те строки, которые соответствуют условию.

Пробую в WHERE вставить CASE, но не знаю, как правильно сделать выборку по условию. К слову, это не единственное условие выборки, до него ещё есть, это условие должно срабатывать по AND.

Comment: Напишите, какой у вас запрос получается. И укажите, какая у вас БД ? MS SQL? MYSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select * from orders where customer = @cust or @cust  is null